# Can someone help walk me through installing PyOpenCL using Cygwin?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, opencl, pyopencl

I cannot figure out how to install pyopencl with Cygwin. Never used Cygwin before so I am very lost as to how I initiate python and use it to run my .py setup files.

Comment: I have never tried this but I definitely will. Meanwhile, if you are using Cygwin, you are Windows. Python+Windows+pyopencl is very easy to setup. I am using it right now. Just saying, you know, so that your work can start right away......

Comment: @Yash   Then by all means, tell me how to install using windows cus I am just not getting it...I'm seriously ready to read through the doc and attempt to make my own wrapper...I am desperate for opencl right now. The kinda crap I need to do requires the speed, but I can't get the system working. :P

Comment: @Yash  Nevermind. I got it working for a py3.2 version. However, it is for the normal python implem. I wanted to use pyopencl on my PythonPortable  imp. But this will do for now. TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, you want to install pyopencl without cygwin on windows, right?

There we go:

In case of you need 32-Bit version, download win32 Packages.

1. Download Python 2.7.5 Windows X86-64 Installer from http://www.python.org/download/ and install python (you rather install it in C:\Python27)
2. Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
3. Download numpy, scipy, pyopencl and install them
4. Go to pypi.python.org/pypi/pytools and download pytools.
5. Extract the file (using i.e. WinRAR) or tar (tar cxvf my.tar.gz)
6. Open commandline aka Dos (cmd.exe) and go in cmd to the folder you have extracted pytools by using cd command
7. Enter in cmd: python setup.py install
8. Open Python IDLE or simply type python in cmd and type import pyopencl

There should be no errors. If so, you did well.

Comment: Sorry. I actually got it up and running. I am going around responding to all my old questions, so you'll get a thumbs up for the effort. :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Python into Cygwin?

- If not, launch setup.exe, get to the packages screen, and do a search for python.
- You can install 2.6.8 and 3 side by side if you want.

After that it's like using python anywhere else. You can do a `$ python my.py` to run my.py. You can install easy_install or pip, etc. if they'll help. Otherwise, follow the directions for PyOpenCL and you should be good!